# How to explode an array and save it in a database

Tags: php, mysqli

I have an array named bookseat in my php file.I've written a code to explode it and save it in my database.

The code is as follows.

```
$bookseat = array(1, 2, 3);
$arrlength = count($bookseat);
$bookseatarray = explode(',', $bookseat);

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'titan3d' AND TABLE_NAME = 'bookings'", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $now = $row['AUTO_INCREMENT'];
} else {
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($bookseatarray); ++$i){
    $SQL_project_has_type = "INSERT INTO bookseat (seat, bid)
    VALUES({$bookseatarray[$i]}, '$now')";
    mysql_query($SQL_project_has_type);
    }

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header('Location: http://localhost/My%20Project/booksuccess.html');
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

The part with the auto incrementation works,but the others doesn't seemed to work.

When the code is on stage,I get an error as "Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\My Project\JSFiles\book.php on line 25".

What might be the error here?Can somebody help please!

Comment: `$bookseat` is already an array, so you don't need to `explode()` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `$bookseat` is already an array of numbers (in this case) you don't need the `explode()` part, just use that array directly...

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($bookseat); ++$i){
    $SQL_project_has_type = "INSERT INTO bookseat (seat, bid)
         VALUES({$bookseat[$i]}, $now)";
    mysqli_query($conn, $SQL_project_has_type);
}
```

And remove...

```
$bookseatarray = explode(',', $bookseat);
```

You should also look into using prepared statements and bind variables.  Also you are mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_`.  So corrected call in the loop.

**Update:**

Also noticed...

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
```

This doesn't seem to be running any SQL in your code.

Comment: $now is the current auto incremented id.So that i can loop and save many seats for one person.

Comment: OK - as it's a number, you can remove the quotes round it.

Comment: The code seems to work fine.But when looked at the database,no values seemed to be stored.But when manually inserting values,the auto incremented id is 3 rows ahead which means the data goes to the database and it stores them,but does not show them.Why is it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$bookseatarray = explode(',', $bookseat);
```

$bookseat is already an array so it won't work; `explode()` should have a string as the 2nd parameter (you're trying to split an array into an array). 
For this to work: `$bookseat = "1,2,3";`

Also don't use `mysql_query` -> `mysqli_query(`....

Answer (score 0):

**I hope this will help you**

I have tested your code. There are few problem in your code which are

1. Your array is in int form but **Explode works when your array input
   is in string form** so you dont need it
2. I prefer use **Foreach** loop for arrays. Through this loop you can easily extract array values.
3. You must define $sql variable
4. Dont use **mysql_query()** because mysql is replaced with **mysqli_query()**

So here is your tested code. "

```
$bookseat = array(1, 2, 3);
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);  
} 

if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'titan3d' AND TABLE_NAME = 'bookings'", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
} else {
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
}
foreach ($bookseat as $key => $value) {
        $SQL_project_has_type = "INSERT INTO bookseat (seat, bid)
        VALUES($value, {$row['AUTO_INCREMENT']})";
        mysqli_query($conn,$SQL_project_has_type);
}
$conn->close();
```

**if your first query is working properly then foreach loop query will work fine. I have replace your $row['AUTO_INCREMENT'] value with random values and it works fine for me**